# MarkerWithLabel gets overlapped by marker on zoom

Tags: google-maps, jquery-gmap3

How do I prevent the markerWithLabel from being overlapped by the marker whenever I zoom in?

I'm currently using gmap3 using this demo https://github.com/jbdemonte/gmap3/blob/master/demo/markerWithLabel.html

To replicate the problem just change the labelAnchor value to "new google.maps.Point(52, 30)" then zoom out then zoom in again.

Comment: Which browser do you use? I have marker overlapped by label on Chrome and FF. And btw both reports error in markerwithlabel.js file: `TypeError: me.marker_.af is undefined`

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I don't see the error "me.marker_.af" on my side. Did you try to zoom out to the max level then try to zoom in again to the max level? the problem seems to only occur when you do this.